# Weird built-in "classic" analyzer?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

This is the official list of built-in analyzers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/analysis-analyzers.html

So what surprised me, that when I used the "classic" for analyzer, it worked, and the result is actually what I want to use:

```
POST /_analyze
{
 "analyzer": "classic",
 "text": "this is a test 123-456-789"
}
```

And gives: **[ test, 123-456-789 ]**

I don't know what this classic analyzer is, but it fits my purpose!
I want to read up on it, to get the details, but there is no info!

There is "classic" tokenizer:

```
POST /_analyze
{
 "tokenizer": "classic",
 "text": "this is a test 123-456-789"
}
```

However, the result is different: **[ this, is, a, test, 123-456-789 ]**

So the question is, anyone knows what this "classic" analyzer is?
And I guess in general, how does one check any built-in analyzer settings in elastic search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ClassicAnalyzer`](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/classic/ClassicAnalyzer.java) is a native Lucene analyzer which is composed of:

- the [`classic` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-classic-tokenizer.html)
- the [`classic` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-classic-tokenfilter.html)
- the [`lowercase` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html)
- the [`stop` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) with a [fixed set of english stop words](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/736d114901e009fa09a6cc8bccbe301a2db03058/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.java#L46-L50)

So the second test you're making is not complete as it's missing the token filters, it should be like this:

```
POST /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "classic",
  "filter": [
    "classic",
    "lowercase",
    "stop"
  ],
  "text": "this is a test 123-456-789"
}
```

And this yields the same tokens as with the `classic` analyzer, i.e. **[ test, 123-456-789 ]**